# R SP library: identicalCRS and parameters in different order

Tags: r, sp

The following returns FALSE:

```
library(sp)
points <- matrix(rnorm(30, 50, 10), ncol=2)
proj1 <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0") 
proj2 <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
sp1 <- SpatialPoints(points, proj1)
sp2 <- SpatialPoints(points, proj2)
identicalCRS(sp1, sp2)
```

However, the proj4strings have the same options, just in a different order. Are the projections truly not equivalent? That is, I'm thinking of replacing identicalCRS with something like

```
length(setdiff(unlist(strsplit(sp1@proj4string@projargs, ' ')), 
               unlist(strsplit(sp2@proj4string@projargs, ' ')))) == 0
```

Comment: To complicate things a bit further,  identical CRS's need not even have the same set of arguments. [See here](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Checking-for-equivalence-of-PROJ4-strings-td7583035.html) for an example, and an (imperfect) function I've used to test for equivalence of PROJ4 strings.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That's nice. Though I wonder too if there are situations where certain points would have the same coordinates even if the CRSs were different.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there are. That's (just) one reason it's far from perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just sort the string?

```
identical(sort(unlist(strsplit(sp1@proj4string@projargs, ' '))), 
          sort(unlist(strsplit(sp2@proj4string@projargs, ' '))))
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that after I posted. Or, just replace the CRS with a sorted version before the comparison (or always...)